# How do I make two overlapping elements on a page scroll at different rates? (examples included)

Tags: html, css

I've started to notice this effect lately on different sites and I find it extremely interesting.

Can someone explain how it is achieved?

for example: http://mayaslava.tumblr.com/

Notice how page slowly encroaches on the top banner as you scroll down?

Here's one more: http://shitpost.asia

Scroll halfway down, see how the text goes faster than the hammer/sickle, but both still change position?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sites like these are known as parallax sites. Tutorial here: http://www.webdesign.org/how-to-create-a-parallax-scrolling-website.22336.html